# Webauthn extension HMACSecret with yubikey

Tags: webauthn, yubico

I'm having trouble understanding how to use webauthn extension [HMAC Secret](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-rd-20180702/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-rd-20180702.html#sctn-hmac-secret-extension) with a yubikey 4 or 5 on a browser.

According to [mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1551594), webauthn extension HMAC secret is now available on Firefox 69.

But if I go to [Webauthn test app](https://webauthntest.azurewebsites.net/#), add a new credential with HMAC Secret set to `true`, then use a yubikey 4 or 5 to create the credential, the credential creation data status is:

**Extension Data**

No extension data

I have the same results on Chrome or Edge

Is it a wrong use on my side? Is the extension not supported by yubikey? Is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

The extension’s primary use case is to generate a secret to lock/unlock an encrypted vault. Part of the secret is held by the client (the salt) and the other part of the secret is attached to the credential on the key. Combining the salt and the credential will produce the secret. Also, two secrets can be generated to allow secret rotation.

Browsers have not implemented the extension.

You can integrate one of Yubico’s libraries directly into your app to take advantage of the functionality.

- https://github.com/Yubico/libfido2
- https://github.com/Yubico/python-fido2
- https://github.com/Yubico/yubikit-ios