# How to retrieve a symmetric key using Webauthn/CTAP HMAC-Secret extension in a web browser?

Tags: encryption, webauthn, fido, yubikey

I am trying to leverage the CTAP hmac-secret extension to retrieve a key for symmetric encryption in a web browser. I have Yubikey5 which implements this extension. I read through the CTAP specs, but I cannot find a reference how to do it once I get the assertion data.

Here's my simplified code:

```
var getCredentialDefaultArgs = {
  publicKey: {
    timeout: 60000,
    allowCredentials: myCredentials,
    challenge: myUint8Array,
    extensions: {
      hmacGetSecret: {
        salt1: "01234567890ABCDEF"
      }
    }
  }
}

navigator.credentials.get(getCredentialDefaultArgs)
.then((assertion) => {
  console.log("assertion", assertion.response.authenticatorData);
  // How do I get my symmetric secret from the authenticatorData ?
  // log just shows: ArrayBuffer(37) {byteLength: 37}
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("assertion error", err);
});
```

I have not been able to find a single **working** example in JavaScript that would utilize this feature in a web browser.

Comment: I haven't got any samples, do see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475657/webauthn-extension-hmacsecret-with-yubikey

Comment: I think this could be potentially done in Javascript but you would have to do all the heavy lifting yourself, as it's not implemented in the browsers.

Comment: Oh, is it possible that the extension is filtered out by the web browser? There's a response so I assumed that the authenticatorData had the extension data.

Comment: 37 bytes is the minimum length for authenticator data, no extension data is present.

Comment: yes, I was wondering if the OS or the browser is even passing this info along. I saw somebody mentioning in a Google group that the extension is only implemented in.create() but not in .get(). I am a little disappointed that this may not be possible on a web application independent of a backend service.

Answer (score 6):

This extension is currently reserved only for platforms. WebAuthn does not have access to it. Might change in future.

Comment: I do hope this will change. Would you have any references to this? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I also wish there was a way to store a secret alongside a WebAuthn credential. :/

Adding to @ackermann-yuriy 's answer: The links I've found RE blocked support for this extension:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1023225
- https://chromestatus.com/feature/5138422207348736
- https://groups.google.com/a/fidoalliance.org/g/fido-dev/c/tosNJvfjMBM?pli=1

Right now (early 2022), the [Large Blob Extension](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-large-blob-extension) seems like the best approach for storing a secret in the authenticator associated with the credential. The good new is that it's [shipping in Chromium](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5657899357437952#details). The bad news is that it's behind a flag and not yet implemented in Firefox or Safari.

Comment: Update: The Large Blob Extension is enabled in desktop Chromium 113
https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-3/#sctn-large-blob-extension